# Print arrays vertically in each column in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a numeric array whose number of rows and columns is known. I want each column in each loop to be printed in a list.

```
$row = 3;
$col = 4;
             
$arr=[
              '1'  , '2'   , '3'   , '4',
              '5' , '6'   ,'7'   , '8',
              '9'  ,'10'  ,'11'  ,'12'
];
```

Output:

```html
<ul>
<li>1<li>
<li>5<li>
<li>9<li>
<ul>
<ul>
<li>2<li>
<li>6<li>
<li>10<li>
<ul>
<ul>
<li>3<li>
<li>7<li>
<li>11<li>
<ul>
<ul>
<li>4<li>
<li>8<li>
<li>12<li>
<ul>
```

i try foreach with array_chunk but The result was displayed in order and horizontally

Comment: This is a 1d array

Comment: Please check: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) Please at least show some of your attempt in solving the problem yourself. Ask specifically about the obstacle instead of pasting the entire problem here untouched.

Comment: @aryanagarwal Yes, what is the problem?

Comment: @KoalaYeung Yes I know i try foreach with array_chunk but The result was displayed in order and horizontally I did not want to clutter the question

Comment: @Dragon: Please show us your PHP code.

Comment: @aryanagarwal: That does happen, sadly :-(

Comment: @CBroe Ops Tnx :))

Comment: @KoalaYeung https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/441e51918980ec36cd5d7cd821f8a8a62b8d947a

Comment: @KoalaYeung I explained the code differently for a better understanding

Comment: CBroe's answer should have [provided your desired output above](https://tehplayground.com/NjxszY8MktMqnbOS), but you're clearly not satisfy with the result. So your simplified example above didn't accurately capture your actual problem. Although your code shown some real work, it is not clear what your real problem is.

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. Show  the desired output and actual output here. Then we can try to help work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i try foreach with array_chunk

Chunks are groups of consecutive items, but the items you want to “group” here are not consecutive.

This is fairly trivial to solve with two nested `for` loops. All you need to do, is *calculate* the correct index to access the correct array element, based on your current row and column number.

(Your naming of the variables seems rather the wrong way around here, but I’ll stick with how you used them for this example.)

```
for($c = 0; $c < $col; ++$c) {
  echo '<ul>';
  for($r = 0; $r < $row; ++$r) {
    echo '<li>' . ($arr[$r * $col + $c]) . '</li>';  
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

You want four `ul` elements, so we loop over “columns” first, and then inside each list, you want three items, so we loop over the number of “rows” in the inner loop.

And then the index to access the proper element simply gets calculated, as current row index times number of columns, plus current column index.

Comment: Thank you, I will test your code